# Name of the effect that one feels entitled to more egoistic behaviour if one commited an altruistic deed

Tags: social-psychology, altruism

I'm looking for the term for the tendency of people to keep a kind of "altruism credit" which means if they help someone else at one moment, they more likely resolve to not helping if they encounter an occasion to help the same day. Alternatively, I'd appreciate any studies which focused on this effect.

Comment: That is [moral licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-licensing).

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg Thank you! Can't believe I wasn't able to find it after 2 hour search

Comment: You're welcome. Closing as [answered in comments](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2163/7001).